# How to retrieve clicked image onPress react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have number of card components in which I'm rendering some images inside. What I'm trying to do is onPress of card retrieving the clicked image.

```
<TouchableOpacity
 onPress={this.viewProduct.bind(this)}
>
<Card>
    <CardItem cardBody>
       <Image source={require('../../assets/images/products/product_1.jpg')} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
                    </CardItem>
                    <CardItem>
                        <Left>
                            <Button transparent>
                                <Text>₹3500</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Right>
                            <Button transparent>
                                <Text style={styles.offText}>50% off</Text>
                            </Button>
                  </Right>

   </CardItem>
</Card>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm rendering the component inside a `TouchableOpacity` to make it as a clickable element and I have attached a function `viewProduct` as a event listner.

```
viewProduct = (item) => {
 console.log(`Selected image is ${item.uri}`);
}
```

But when I click the function I'm not getting the clicked Image. Is there anything I have to bind inside the function or how to retrieve the image onPress of Card.

Comment: you need to pass a second argument to the bind function, like so `onPress={this.viewProduct.bind(this, item)}`

Comment: I changed the question a little. Item is not defined

Comment: @Musthafa What do you want to send to the `viewProduct`. What is `item`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the image inside the `viewProduct` function. So that I can use the image inside another component to view the product.

Comment: if you want to interact with the imageview, you could create ref and pass it to image and add the ref to function args. but if you want some props of image maybe it's better to pass the prop from parent to child and pass that props on function argumants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre directly giving it a source. you need to extract that into a separate obj and parse that as your image source
check out this snippet:
https://snack.expo.io/@karanwadhwa/stack-overflow-62977355

edit: updated above snack to use local files instead

Comment: @Musthafa I've used remote uris for this example but if thats not what you were looking for and want a workaround for local files let me know i'll update my snack

Comment: This method is actually working. But here I'm trying to load from my local source

Comment: So I have to use firebase storage to load my images.

Comment: Thanks dear. It's worked!! So we have to require the images if it's in local.